# Use a Dictionary generated from CSV to update values in .xlsx file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, openpyxl

Every day I am given an old Excel 95 file of data. It has columns up to the letter 'L' and hundreds of rows. 
Column 'B' is a customer reference number, it's unique to each customer.
Column 'I' is a dollar value.

Each morning I need to use this file to update another Excel file. I search for the customer reference number, and enter the dollar value. The columns for the Customer reference and Dollar value in the Destination file are 'D' and 'E' respectively.

As I'm new to python I thought this would be a good project to automate. After research and installation of a few other modules (and reading the Automate the Boring stuff with python book) I haven't yet had any success.

I'm saving the source file as a csv, then importing csv, then turning it into a dictionary in python. This works fine and I'm happy with it.

My problem is trying to write the values to the destination file. I get no errors, the file saves at the end, but when I open it the values are not there. I'm not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

```
import os, csv, openpyxl

os.chdir('nameOfMyDirectory')

print('What is the name of the source file?')
sourceFileName = input()

print('What is the key column?')
keyColumn = int(input())

print('What is the value column?')
valueColumn = int(input())

source = csv.reader(open(sourceFileName + '.csv'))
sourceDictionary = {}
for row in source:
    key = row[keyColumn]
    sourceDictionary[key] = row[8]
```

Everthing above here seems to work, I can use the interactive shell to print the dollar values using the key column. I've included it incase I'm wrong and this needs to change too.

Below is where the problem seems to be (I think)

```
print('What is the destination file name?')
destinationFileName = input()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(destinationFileName + '.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('nameOfMySheet')

allRows = sheet.max_row

for rowNum in range(2, allRows): #Start from row 2 and go to the end
    membershipID = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=4).value
    if membershipID in sourceDictionary:
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=5).value = sourceDictionary[membershipID]


wb.save('newFileName.xlsx')
```

The program runs and there are no errors. The new file is saved with the filename but the values are not updated, they are still blank.

I wasn't sure if the openpyxl column = 4 value was one of those ones that started from 1 or 0, so I've tried counting from both, and both don't work.

Any help is super appreciated.

---

I've been asked to show some example data so here is a link to 2 google sheets that are identical to the source file csv and destination file xlsx. Hope this helps. [Link to sheets](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bz9zCfS5szC4RVFvdEg3VGF6T1U?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to update the 'Destination File's Column E', with the 'Source Files Column I'. I use the customer ID column as the reference.

Comment: Can you post data to illustrate what you are saying? Specifically current layout and desired result?

Comment: I've added a link to 2 google sheets in my question. Hope this helps.

Comment: I suspect the `if` clause is evaluating to `False`. You could put some debugging code like a print statement in there to check.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the problem is a type mismatch. The keys read in from csv are in `string` format and the values read in from the Excel sheet are `float` values. So the `if` statement to match the two always return *false*.

To align the data types, adjust following line in second `for` loop where first you cast to integer and then to string:

```
membershipID = str(int(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=4).value))
```